# Kotlin Stateflow get one-but-last value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

In my `viewModel` i have a `StateFlow<Destination>`, with those values:

```
enum class Destination {
    FIRST_SCREEN,
    SECOND_SCREEN,
    THIRD_SCREEN,
    FOURTH_SCREEN,
}
```

Somewhere in my `activity` i use this flow for navigation:

```
viewModel.destinations[...]
.collect { destination ->
    fragmentManager.navigateTo(
        when(destination){
            FIRST_SCREEN -> FirstScreenFragment(),
            SECOND_SCREEN -> SecondScreenFragment(),
            THIRD_SCREEN -> ThirdScreenFragment(),
            FOURTH_SCREEN -> FourthScreenFragment(),
        }
    )
}
```

...where `navigateTo()` is very simple in the moment

```
fun FragmentManager.navigateTo(fragment: Fragment) {
    beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

I would now like to add transitions ~ like in a `viewPager`.
The animations themselves are a piece of cake, but i need to know in which direction to animate:
Am i moving "forward" or "backward", which boils down to:

Is my current destination `<` or `>` my new destination?

- i could use the fragment-backstack (but i and [a few others](https://youtu.be/nP_B5-jrbsY?t=2493) hate it)
- i could simply use a variable in my activity storing the last screen we navigated to, but that feels hacky
- i could try to use flows for that, but i have no real idea how to do that. Any suggestions?

An optimal usage would look like:

```
viewModel.destinations[...]
    .rememberHistory()
    .collect { currentDestination, lastDestination ->
}
```

Comment: There's example in the [StateFlows](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) docs, as StateFlows only hold one value, so "Use SharedFlow when you need a StateFlow with tweaks in its behavior such … replaying more values". I'm not certain, but I think you want a [SharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/index.html) with a `replay = 2`.

Comment: You could also try accumulating the StateFlow into a `Pair` accumulator using [runningFold](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/running-fold.html).

Comment: Do go for sealead class instead of enum

Comment: @pvn why should i? An enum is totally fine here

Comment: @m.reiter https://medium.com/android-news/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering how i solved this:

I used [runningFold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/running-fold.html)

```
data class DestinationHistory(val previous: Destination?, val current: Destination)

val destinationHistory: Flow<DestinationHistory> = destination.runningFold(
    initial = DestinationHistory(previous = null, current = Destination.FIRST_SCREEN)
) { history, newDestination ->
    DestinationHistory(
        previous = history.current,
        current = newDestination
    )
}
```

Effectively this maps the destination-flow to a "pair" of previous & current destination.